# Wordpress Javascript File SRC File Path

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

In my Wordpress site I am using some JavaScript code for an interactive part.

When the file is local I just call `anyPlus.src = "solarZoom.png";`.

I have tried many ways and can't figure out how to get the image from the file path once it's on my server. I tried `/powerbox/Tour/solarZoom.png`, `../Tour/solarZoom.png`, `Tour/solarZoom.png`, `/Tour/solarZoom.png`, `/solarZoom.png`.

In my style I would call it as "`../Tour/solarZoom.png`" but it is not working in the javascript.

I have attached an image of my hierarchy. My root is /powerbox/index.php.

[image]

Comment: /powerbox/Tour/solarZoom.png didn't work?

Comment: nope. I tried /powerbox/Tour/solarZoom.png, ../Tour/solarZoom.png, Tour/solarZoom.png, /Tour/solarZoom.png, /solarZoom.png

Comment: Interesting. Try messing around with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path";` and other parameters and see what that yields

Comment: in my php and css it works fine

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Why is your template folder the root?

Comment: @Ben sorry for the poor wording on that

Comment: @BDGapps so your absolute path to the template folder is `/wp-content/themes/powerbox` ?

Comment: @ben yes sorry for that

Comment: yes the javascript is being called and the functions work it just can't find the correct image

Comment: @BDGapps just hard-code the absolute path `/wp-content/themes/powerbox/Tour/something.png`

Comment: @Ben I am slightly confused. When I hard coded the path it still didn't work but in my index.php I use "src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Tour/hotspot.png" and it works.

Comment: @Ben I finally got it to work with: http://frankfusion.com/powerbox/wp-content/themes/powerbox/Tour/IMG_HERE.png I am doing this for a client and CAN NOT hard code this how do I get it dynamically?

Comment: @BDGapps what are the locations of the js and css files you are referring to in your question, according to your file hierarchy? (E.g. for the css file you mentioned "In my style I would call it as..." but you don't indicate the actual css and js files you are referencing the image from in your file hierarchy image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the informations I could collect about your problem I can only solve it by this:

Take your index.php - file on the same level where your javascript.js - file is located, add

```
<script>var ABSPATH = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/Tour/javascript.js"></script>
```

into your `<head>` - tag. Now you have your Template-URL-prefix in the variable `ABSPATH`. Change your function `hotSpotFunc(part)` located in here:
http://frankfusion.com/powerbox/wp-content/themes/powerbox/Tour/javascript.js on line 24:

```
anyPlus.src="http://frankfusion.com/powerbox/wp-content/themes/powerbox/"+imgName;
```

must be now

```
anyPlus.src=ABSPATH+imgName;
```

and then it should work without hardcoding the template url as you have it right now.

Worth to mention some other things:

1. [every wordpress theme has a header.php - file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) where this stuff shall go. Read something about WP Theme Development: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
2. [Do not use global variables or global function names](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals) as you do right now in your javascript.
3. make a solid structure in your wordpress - folder. Do you really need a child theme for this project? It looks a bit messy right now.
4. The current "solution" is a dirty one. Use the advice from @brasofilo, as he showed up a clean solution.

Comment: If it was a child theme, I think `bloginfo('template_url')` wouldn't work, the recommended way is `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` as it looks first in the child folder and then in the parent (and it's equivalent to `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`). But looks like [it's not a child](http://frankfusion.com/powerbox/wp-content/themes/powerbox/style.css)... Although yours and Seth answers are similar, this one is *very complete*, kudos for that +1

Answer (score 2):

Enqueue your JavaScript using [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and pass the correct URL through [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b5f_enqueue_scripts' );

function b5f_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script(
        'tour-script', // Handle
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/Tour/javascript.js', // File url
        array( 'jquery' ) // Dependencies
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tour-script' );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'tour-script', 
        'localize_vars', 
        array( 
            'url' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri(),
            'path' => get_stylesheet_directory(),
            'solar' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/Tour/solarZoom.png'
        ) 
    );
}
```

And in your `javascript.js` file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
    console.log( localize_vars.url ); 
    $("body").prepend('<img src="'+ localize_vars.solar + '" />');
});
```

`wp_localize_script` was created to pass translated strings to JavaScript files, but it can be used to pass anything really. Just fill that array with other data and access it in the JS variable `localize_vars.DATA`.

Comment: So I do: anyPlus.src=localize_vars.url + '/Tour/solarZoom.png'

Comment: How would I check? I have a role over that when I hover over it the image enlarges and then changes to solarZoom.png.

Comment: I tried: alert(localize_vars.path + '/Tour/solarZoom.png'); and it didn't do anything

Comment: I just checked the dev in firefox and received RefrenceError: localize_vars is not defined

Comment: @BDGapps, I've updated the Answer including jQuery as a dependency and with a working example. I tested adding `wp_enqueue_scripts` in TwentyEleven's `functions.php` file and creating a JS and PNG files inside `/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/Tour/*.*`. Works for me, hope it helps.

Comment: So do I still use: anyPlus.src=localize_vars.url + '/Tour/solarZoom.png'; anywhere I need in my js file.So do I still use: anyPlus.src=localize_vars.url + '/Tour/solarZoom.png'; anywhere I need in my js file.

Comment: @BDGapps, updated the Answer with a shortcut for the PNG file. I really cannot help any longer without seeing how you're encoding your JS and the contents of this JS file. As I said, I tested this exact code, replicating your directory structure and file names and it's working ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in your header define this above all scripts that will reference your images....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ABSPATH = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";
</script>
```

Now when referencing an image do `anyPlus.src = ABSPATH + "/Tour/solarZoom.png";`

Comment: i get ABSPATH not defined

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/Tour/javascript.js">
 var ABSPATH = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";
 
</script>

Comment: Are you putting it above all script tags? This needs to be the very first javascript that loads. I just copy and pasted it into a current project and it's worked perfectly.

Comment: Wrong order. FIRST you need to declare the variable `ABSPATH`:
<script>var ABSPATH = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/Tour/javascript.js"></script> and then you load your javascript.js - file in your index.php.

By the way, the clean way would be the answer of brasofilo.