# Basic Integration of Edge Animate and WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a very basic file I created in Edge Animate in which I just fadein and fadeout some text. It's located here:

http://www.threecell.com/demo/simpletext/simpletext.html

Edge Animate exports an HTML file and some JS Files. My question is whether it's possible to make it so that you can update the text in the future using the WordPress framework.  I found that the actual text is declared in one of the JS files which I've posted below (the text in question is "THIS IS A TEST".) Ultimately, I'd like to create a WordPress widget that goes into this JS file and changes the text value.

Thanks in advance for any assistance or guidance,

```
/**
 * Adobe Edge: symbol definitions
 */
(function($, Edge, compId){
//images folder
var im='images/';

var fonts = {};


var resources = [
];
var symbols = {
"stage": {
   version: "2.0.1",
   minimumCompatibleVersion: "2.0.0",
   build: "2.0.1.268",
   baseState: "Base State",
   initialState: "Base State",
   gpuAccelerate: false,
   resizeInstances: false,
   content: {
         dom: [
         {
            id:'Text',
            type:'text',
            rect:['131','190','auto','auto','auto','auto'],
            text:"THIS IS A TEST",
            font:['Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',24,"rgba(0,0,0,1)","normal","none",""]
         }],
         symbolInstances: [

         ]
      },
   states: {
      "Base State": {
         "${_Stage}": [
            ["color", "background-color", 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'],
            ["style", "overflow", 'hidden'],
            ["style", "height", '400px'],
            ["style", "width", '550px']
         ],
         "${_Text}": [
            ["style", "top", '200px'],
            ["style", "opacity", '0'],
            ["style", "left", '197px']
         ]
      }
   },
   timelines: {
      "Default Timeline": {
         fromState: "Base State",
         toState: "",
         duration: 1500,
         autoPlay: true,
         timeline: [
            { id: "eid7", tween: [ "style", "${_Text}", "opacity", '1', { fromValue: '0'}], position: 0, duration: 1500 },
            { id: "eid4", tween: [ "style", "${_Text}", "left", '297px', { fromValue: '197px'}], position: 0, duration: 1500 },
            { id: "eid5", tween: [ "style", "${_Text}", "top", '193px', { fromValue: '200px'}], position: 0, duration: 1500 }         ]
      }
   }
}
};


Edge.registerCompositionDefn(compId, symbols, fonts, resources);

/**
 * Adobe Edge DOM Ready Event Handler
 */
$(window).ready(function() {
     Edge.launchComposition(compId);
});
})(jQuery, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-2538351");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to [create a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and use the [Widgets_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

In the frontend, the widget will use `wp_enqueue_script` to load `simpletext_edgePreload.js`. And then pass your text values as JavaScript data with `wp_localize_script`.
You'll finally be able to use something like this in your JS file: `text:my_data.text`.

A shortcode example: [Wordpress Javascript File SRC File Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304870/1287812).

A widget example: [Conditionally enqueue a widget's script/stylesheet in HEAD](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47606/12615)

Comment: Hey Brasofilo, Huge thanks for the resources. I'm going to check out the links. I chose the widget / plugin route since that made the most sense to me. Do you agree with that direction or is there a better / simpler method of achieving what I'm looking for?

Comment: A Shortcode will be easier and more flexible, and [can be coupled with the Text Widget](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77786/12615). A Widget will provide a [nice interface](http://wordpress.org/plugins/stack-exchange-posts-widget/screenshots/), but you'll be restricted to the sidebars. And, 99% of the cases, [use a plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) and not `functions.php`.

Comment: Thx. This may seem like an obvious question, but by shortcode you are referring to plugin correct?